# Is there a way for me to strip away div classes and other CSS stuff when generating grails views?

Tags: grails

Well, there goes my question. I really don't like the UI, and if there was a way to auto generate only the essential things like the fields but no divs and classes. I know about removing the css, but I really just want the raw html like what rails gives me. Anybody know how?

For example, `grails generate-views myStuff` generates code that looks like this:

```
<table>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean:feedback,field:'name','errors')}">
                                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="${fieldValue(bean:feedback,field:'name')}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="feedback">Feedback:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean:feedback,field:'feedback','errors')}">
                                <input type="text" id="feedback" name="feedback" value="${fieldValue(bean:feedback,field:'feedback')}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 



                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

When I'm only interested in getting this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="${fieldValue(bean:feedback,field:'name')}"/>
<input type="text" id="feedback" name="feedback" value="${fieldValue(bean:feedback,field:'feedback')}"/>
```

Well, I could always do stuff manually and not auto-generate, but, no it's not practical when the fields are too many. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [install-templates](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) command to install the templates. Then you can edit/modify the templates to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it and see if it fits my needs.

Comment: Any luck on modifying the templates to meet your needs?